# I want to switch to a branch having name tempBranch in remote repository or origin using git Bash

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have these branches in remote or origin
1. master
2. tempBranch
3. tempBranch2

I have these branches locally
1.master
2.tempBranch

when i  `git checkout tempBranch`  in gitbash it changes the branch to tempBranch but the code shown in this branch is different from the one i have in remote.
I want to see the same code as I have in tempBranch. How to do that.

Comment: How did you create `tempBranch` locally ?

Comment: git checkout -b tempBranch    in gitbash

Answer (score 2):

If the `tempBranch` you have locally, is set-up to track the remote `tempBranch` you should be able to pull down the latest changes from the remote branch.

Whilst in the `tempBranch`:

```sh
git pull
```

If the `tempBranch` is not tracking the remote branch, set the upstream branch and then pull changes:

```sh
git branch -u origin/tempBranch
git pull
```

The `-u` flag is a shorthand for `--set-upstream`

Answer (score 0):

Always when you checkout to a different branch, we need to pull the code from the repository to the local branch ( syncing the code to the local branch)

`git checkout tempBranch3`

`git pull origin tempBranch3`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily. create a new branch in the locality, then pull remote branch to that branch.keep in mind that after creating the new branch you need to switch to that branch before pulling
 lets say your new branch is A.
type below codes:
  git checkout A
  git branch -u origin/tempBranch

If you want to keep "tempBranch2" and branch "A", merge it